# Laravel 5.2 Create Database from Migration

Tags: laravel

is there anyway I could setup(create) database from migration?
I want to run migrate and seed, but beforehand it should create database first.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: You would potentially need higher permissions than you would want to give to your Laravel user in order to create a database. It might be better to create your database and user separately from your application code using a privileged account.

Answer (score 7):

You could [create custom artisan command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#writing-commands) and run it before `migrate` command.

Inside the command use raw query, you can try something like this:

```
DB::statement('CREATE DATABASE :db', ['db' => $newDatabase]);
```

Comment: He also needs to modify the environment parameters

Comment: what environment parameters?

Comment: @HongbinWang, true. ans4175, you'll also need to create new connection to use created database.

Comment: @ans4175, I've found pretty elegant example of doing that. It's for Laravel 4, but it should work for Laravel 5 too. Look for JohnathonKoster's post here: http://laravel.io/forum/09-13-2014-create-new-database-and-tables-on-the-fly

Comment: Practically I want to create database before running test in wercker

Comment: I have no idea why this question is upvoted. It's apparent no one has tried it because PDO doesn't support binding for database, table, or column names. The `:db` part can only be for values in queries, not for names. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53210496

Answer (score 0):

> you can do this by new **Artisan Command**...

```
php artisan make:database {database-name} {connection-name}
```

but you have to creat this command first.

check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36914573/how-to-create-new-empty-database-with-laravel-over-model/59602936#59602936)

[How to create new empty database with Laravel over Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36914573/how-to-create-new-empty-database-with-laravel-over-model/59602936#59602936)

Comment: I guess this command doesn't exist by the latest version. I tried and it said "Did you mean." and database is not among the suggested keywords.